# React native webview using script in html of source parameter works on iOS but not on android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview

I have this react native webview setup shown below. It works well with iOS but shows a blank page on Android.

I am using RN 0.63.3 and RNWebview 11.15.0

How can I resolve this issue?

```
<WebView
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onRouteChange}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={`(${ReportJS})()`}
        injectedJavaScriptForMainFrameOnly={true}
        onMessage={onMessage}
        onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
        style={styles.webview}
        ref={webViewRef}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{
          html: `
            <body>
              <script>${startupJS}</script>
            </body>
        `,
        }}
        
      />
```

This is the function inside `ReportJS`:

```
[window, document].forEach((el) =>
    el.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      let data = 'success';
      if (location.href.startsWith('<redacted url>')) {
        const inputElement = document.querySelector(
          "form input[name='response']",
        );
        data = inputElement?.value;
      }
      if (data === undefined) {
        data = 'Hello!';
      }
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data);
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the file set as `injectedJavascript` variable within the page instead of using an external file resolved my issue